# Running 64bit jvm on 32bit OS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, tomcat, jvm

Can we use 64bit JVM with Tomcat64bit for 32bit OS. The OS is Amazon Linux machine 32bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot run a 64 bit application on a 32 bit operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You miss some more description: If the system/os is 32 bit, and the software is all 64bit, then you cannot. Hence the distinction between i686 (32 bit) and x86_64 (64 bit) architectures.
You should check for the documentation on that Tomcat software.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that.
But instead, you can run 32bit JVM on 64bit OS.